# node.js ipfs-api add and read a file

Tags: node.js, file, ipfs

I have a ipfs daemon running on localhost. I am trying to run the following simple program, after creating `/tmp/afile.txt` . I am unable to access the file. code and error follow. I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/ipfs-api

```
const fs = require("fs");

let ipfs = require('ipfs-api')({host: "localhost", port: 5001, protocol: "http"});
let fileStream = fs.createReadStream("/tmp/afile.txt");
ipfs.files.add(fileStream, function (err, files) {
  ipfs.files.cat(files[0].hash, function (err, file) {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log(file);
  });
})
```

Output:

```
Error: this dag node is a directory
   at parseError (/Users/amarshanand/InfoStore/node_modules/ipfs-api/src/utils/send-request.js:16:17)
   at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/amarshanand/InfoStore/node_modules/ipfs-api/src/utils/send-request.js:39:14)
```

Edit: I got it to work by reading the file first and creating a Buffer out of it, but not using ReadStream. Still awaiting an answer.

```
const fs = require("fs");

let ipfs = require('ipfs-api')({host: "localhost", port: 5001, protocol: "http"});
let cont = fs.readFileSync("/tmp/afile.txt");
cont = new Buffer(cont);
ipfs.add(cont, function (err, files) {
  if(err) throw err;
  ipfs.files.cat(files[0].hash, function (err, file) {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log(file.toString());
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do a .cat on the hash of /tmp. You can quickly understand what is happening if you do a console.log on that files array (console.log(files) before the files.cat).

To fix your issue, you need to point at the correct element of the array, in your case it will be one. So your code will work with:

```
  ipfs.files.cat(files[1].hash, function (err, file) {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log(file);
  });
```

Let me know if it works for you :)

Comment: the problem stays. console.log(files) show [ { path: 'tmp/afile.txt',
    hash: 'QmUNLLsPACCz1vLxQVkXqqLX5R1X345qqfHbsf67hvA3Nn',
    size: 4 },
  { path: 'tmp',
    hash: 'QmYbmaVErtQQWV37iR6igseV5rxZE1T1DNDhqAsuanb2Hb',
    size: 59 } ], which seems to say that both of the entries are dirs